# Why is a echo-request ping packet 84 bytes in the log of iptables?

Tags: iptables, wireshark, packet

When I log the length of a echo-request packet,

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG`

I saw the length was `LEN=84`, but in wireshark, the captured packet size was `0x60`, why does it differ?

Answer (score 1):

The `LEN` is decimal where the `0x` in the `wireshark` output indicates hexadecimal.  `16 * 6 = 96`

If you are looking at the `Ethernet` frame, then you would have to subtract `14` or `18` (with vlan tag) from that leaving me with either `82` or `78`. If this is the size of the encapsulating `IP` packet, then this would be rather big and lead me to assume you adjusted the size with `ping -s`

Normally an icmp type 8 packet generated by Linux ipv4 ping without arguments has `48` bytes of "data" with `16` bytes of `ICMP` header and `20` bytes `IP` header leaving you with a `84` Byte `IP` packet. so are you sure you are looking at the right number in wireshark?

(This isn't really an answer but it's too long for a comment to make sense)